# Is a WW2 German bank note with a LITZMANNSTAND symbol possibly fake?

Tags: world-war-two, german

Was German currency used in the Lodz ghetto?

I recently bought a 50 reichsmark bank note which has got a LITZMANNSTAND symbol stamped on it in red ink, are these fake?

Here's what the seller replied when I challenged them over the authenticity of the stamps.

> There have been over-stamped Polish and Germany banknotes during WWII 1939-45, and also genuine stamped banknotes from the Protektorat B.u.M. You will find lots of "stamped" notes from German occupied Poland and Polish ZŁOTY banknotes over-stamped by various units of the AK (or Home Army) operating in Warsaw. German party "ss" organizations used to stamp official orders, cancel stamps, indicate a document was received and/or processed by an official and for other miscellaneous documents.

---

Sorry my mistake, I copied & pasted seller's description, it should be the later spelling. These answers have confirmed what I thought, I read on another forum that Germany didn't allow their currency to be used outside of Germany during WW2.

Comment: Photos would help

Comment: could you edit the question to fix the mistake you reference?]

Comment: If you think one of the answers answered the question you had, you should consider "accepting" one of them by clicking the checkmark next to it. Otherwise people are likely to think the question still requires an answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. Since 'Tony' is an unregistered user, and has since posted two 'answers' with a different profile of the same name, what do they need to do to get back to the original profile to accept an answer?

Comment: @SteveBird - Honestly, not sure. I've never used an unregistered account. There's probably a meta.se question about it.

Answer (score 5):

At first glance, this sounds like a fake.

There is no mention of overprinted German notes.
The statement from the seller is correct, but not for Łódź/Litzmannstadt (they dodged the question).

Starting on the 24th of June 1940, German and Polish banknotes had to be exchanged for **Mark-Quittungen** (Mark Receipts), initially only as paper notes. The exchange had to be completed by the 8th of July 1940, 18.00h.

Notes for 50 Pf, 1,2,5,10,20 and 50 Marks were designed inside but printed outside the Ghetto. Altogether, notes for 7348 Million Marks were issued.

[image]
[image]

In the summer of 1942, coins were also issued.

---

**Source**:

- [Die Banknoten und Münzen des Gettos in Lodz : Mark-Quittungen von Litzmannstadt
  Autor(en): Zagorowski, Michael M.
  Ob](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng%3Fpid%3Dsmb-001%253A2019%253A69%253A%253A163&ved=2ahUKEwiuguvTqtj7AhWbVPEDHUzXB34QFnoECDIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2oh6KGUhNdjSVczryWd6sp) (PDF)

Answer (score 4):

Well, this certainly needs more scrutiny:

Lotz (German: Litzmannstadt) had *their own* currency.

> When the ghetto was created, its inhabitants were forced to exchange their cash and valuables for the *ghetto mark*. **Other** large ghettos in Poland adopted a different approach: they were allowed to use banknotes of the Polish zloty and small denominations of the **German Reichsmark with unique stamps** indicating that this currency can only be used in the ghetto.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodz_Ghetto_mark).

I also hope it was your own typo here that made you say "LITZMANNSTA**ND**" instead of the correct Litzmannsta**dt**. Because that is plain wrong and looks like either someone did not know German, or had autocorrect on and did not pay attention. I have a hard time imagining any German using a wrong stamp for something like this. It's not like a one time typo in a hastily typed up document.

So, the city is spelled wrong and on top, *that* specific ghetto actually *didn't* do that. All others did. Smells like a fake.